# How instantly send email when record enters to Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, automationstudio, triggered-send

Who can explain in detail how to do so that when a record enters to the Data Extension (from DE Manager form), an email is instantly sent to her? I read [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297595/how-to-send-transaction-email-when-record-added-in-marketing-cloud-data-extensio/366490#366490) article, tried to set up api events, tried different journies, but nothing works. Can some one help me, please?

Comment: You can't do this with just DE Manager and Journey Builder. You will need to build a custom form handler, which in addition to storing the record in a data extension, will also trigger an email. Here are few examples: https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/create-a-form-handler/ and https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/build-html-forms-without-smart-capture/ - they need to be extended with email trigger, like this one: https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/create-a-triggered-send/

Comment: The article you shared should work. API, File triggered, etc..

Comment: @LukasLunow thank you!